# Vector at() out of range error after initializing

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector

Hello all (first post to SO here).
I am working on a text based C++ game (Ants vs Some Bees) as a side project where I have a vector of Insect pointers that I initialize in an init function

```
void Colony::initBoard()
{
    vector<Insect*> gameBoard (10, nullptr);

    //check to see that vector is properly intialized
    for (auto &it : gameBoard)
    {
        std::cout << it << std:: endl;
    };
    //check the size
    cout << gameBoard.size() << endl;
}
```

The next goal is to place some of the Ants at a specified point in the vector, and my ant class inherits from the insect class. This is where I am getting a vector out of range error when using the .at() method, and the vector shows a size of zero.

```
void Colony::createAnt()
{   
    int position = 0;
    cout << "Where do you want to set your Ant? " << endl;
    cin >> position;
    //checking for size (0 here for some reason)
    cout << gameBoard.size() << endl;

    ...//validation stuff done here, not relevant to post

    gameBoard.at(position) = new Ant(position);
    isOccupied = true;
}
```

When running this code in main, I get a size of 10 when the init function is called, and a size of 0 when the place ant is called, and I am not sure why.

My main function so far which is just testing the functionality of this function.

```
    Colony col;
    col.initBoard();
    col.createAnt();
```

`vector<Insect*> gameBoard;` is the private member variable in the Colony class. My thoughts is that the vector is somehow going out of scope, but I am not sure how to fix. Thanks in advance for any tips/suggestions

Comment: gameBoard is a local variable of function initBoard that hides the member variable with the same name (that you say is there). This is the reason why you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I was creating a new vector in the init function for some reason. After initializing properly in the constructor I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

In `initBoard()`, you have declared a local variable named `gameBoard` that you are filling instead of the class member of the same name.

Change this line:

```
vector<Insect*> gameBoard (10, nullptr);
```

To this instead:

```
gameBoard.resize (10, nullptr);
```

That being said, since you know the number of elements at compile time, consider using a fixed array instead of a `std::vector`, eg:

```
std::array<Insect*, 10> gameBoard;
```

Either way, you should be storing `std::unique_ptr<Insect>` elements instead of raw `Insect*` pointers, eg:

```
gameBoard.at(position).reset(new Ant(position));
```

Or:

```
gameBoard.at(position) = std::make_unique<Ant>(position);
```